# Как сделать, чтобы срабатывало только 1 раз?

Tags: android

Поставлен такой код на слежку об окончании прокрутки. Но почему то он срабатывает 2 раза. Как сделать, чтобы он срабатывал только один раз

```
 ((RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec)).setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

                if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
System.out.println("Wew");
                            checkLine();
                    }
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Решением в лоб может быть булевый флаг, который не даст попасть в блок if

Comment: @gil9red, решение супер. Но показывает, что после окончания прокрутки, есть ещё одна. То есть он остановился а потом ещё 1 начал прокрутку, а потом снова остановился

Comment: Объект модели имеется?